# How to export a report expression in Cognos 10 as a data item and return the results when choosing Excel 2007 data

Tags: excel, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have quick question about Cognos 10. I am trying to export a data item which I created that has a report expression as the value. The value is for example : IF(ParamValue('p_RPO') is NULL) THEN (' ') ELSE (ParamDisplayValue('p_RPO')). When I export the report out as a HTML it works as intended. However when I select excel 2007 data it seems to remove the data item column that has then report expression. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a report expression add a data item to the query with this expression:

```
if (?p_RPO? is null) then ('whatever') else (?p_RPO?)
```

Add this data item to the list.

To make the p_RPO parameter optional you have to use the prompt macro specifying a default value. In this case:

```
if(#prompt('p_RPO', 'string', 'default')# = 'default') then ('whatever') else (#prompt('p_RPO', 'string', 'default')#)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it did seem to validate. I noticed on the prompt page when I began to run the report it made the prompt required even though its not a required prompt and the properties is required field is set to no and the hide adornments is set to No as well. Any reason why would it make it required?

Comment: I figured out the reason why it makes the prompt required. I believe it must be built into Cognos where it the prompt is set to required when adding expressions into a data item. One of my requirements from my end user was to make that particular prompt "not required" because they may or may not use it. However, the expression does work when exporting out to Excel Format and the other format but using Excel Data it hides the columns because its expecting "true data" or "raw data" as I like to call it.

Comment: Try to use a dummy query item in the expression. Maybe that way the column is displayed in excel